# Powershell get enumerator in loop

Tags: powershell, hashtable, enumeration

I'm trying to get the enumerator while looping a hash table.

I do understand how it works in a `foreach` loop like the following:

```
$test = @{set01 = '0'; set02 = '1'}
foreach ($t in $test.GetEnumerator()) {
    Write-Host 'key: '$t.Key
}
```

Which would output the individual key per loop:

```
key:  set02
key:  set01
```

I'd like to know if it is possible to do that in a C type loop such as:

```
$test = @{set01 = '0'; set02 = '1'}
for ($i = 0; $i -lt 1; $i++) {
    Write-Host 'key: '$test.Keys[$i] # edited with Dandré's answer.
}
```

Which lists all the keys:

```
key:  set02 set01
key:
```

Is that possible or does the `.GetEnumerator()` only work in a `foreach` situation?

**edit:** Reading [mklement0's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55549583/7971841) answer i see that it's not directly possible. I'll mark it as the answer for the detailed explanation.

One workaround i figured out to extract the key for the loop position is partially linked to [Dandré's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55549621/7971841) answer combined with mklement0's explanation.

If the keys are collected into an array prior to running the loop they can be looked up while running the for loop.

```
$test = @{set01 = '0'; set02 = '1'}

$keys = @($test.Keys)

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $test.Count; $i++) {
    Write-Host 'key:'$keys[$i]
}
```

This will result as expected:

```
key: set02
key: set01
```

depending on the array the keys need to be reversed first `[array]::Reverse($keys)`.

The `$keys` variable can also be used within the loop to call specific keys as in: `$test[$keys[$i]]`. It's a bit of a hack but opens some interesting possibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a *hashtable*, whose entries cannot be accessed with positional *indices* (`0`, `1`, ...); instead what you specify inside `[...]` is an entry *key*.

Therefore, use the `.Keys` property for enumeration:

```
$test = @{set01 = '0'; set02 = '1'}
foreach ($key in $test.Keys) {
  $key 
  # To access the entry's *value*, use $test[$key] $test[$key]
}
```

The result is:

```
set02
set01
```

Note how the keys were enumerated in a different order than they were defined, because `[hashtable]` instances do not guarantee any particular enumeration order.

In PSv3+ you can use an *ordered* hashtable to remedy that, which would also allow you to use positional indexing - but note that positional indexing then returns the entry *values*, not the keys:

```
$test = [ordered] @{set01 = '0'; set02 = '1'}
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $test.Count; $i++) {
  $test[$i]
}
```

Note: While you *could* use `$test.Keys[$i]` to access the keys, as in [Dandre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55549621/45375), direct enumeration of the keys with `foreach ($key in $test.Keys)` is less verbose and faster; the only good reason to use index-based iteration with `$test.Keys[$i]` would be if index `$i` weren't just a *helper* variable, but were required for operation, such as for outputting a string that reflects both a key and its index.

The above therefore yields:

```
0
1
```

Note that the **`for` syntax is not only verbose, it actually performs worse than `foreach`**, and **in case you do need explicit indices, use `foreach` with the indices generated via the range operator (`..`)**, which is not only faster but also arguably more readable than the `for` loop:

```
$test = [ordered] @{set01 = '0'; set02 = '1'}
foreach ($i in 0..($test.Count-1)) {
   $test[$i]
}
```

While it is less memory-efficient, because the array of indices must be created as a whole up front, that is usually not a concern.

Answer (score 3):

Agreeing with @mklement0.
If you want the traditional `for`-loop you could do the following using the `Keys` property.

```bsh
$test = @{set01 = '0'; set02 = '1'}

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $test.Count; $i++) {
    Write-Host $test.Keys[$i]
}
```

This will output: `set02 set01`

Comment: +1 for a direct fix of the OP's attempt, but it's worth noting that unless the index variable is truly needed as such in the loop body - not just as an enumeration _helper_ variable - `foreach ($key in $test.Keys) { ... }` is a more direct and concise expression of the intent that is also faster than a `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i edited the original post with your answer to explain the different output between `foreach` and the `for` loop.